# iPad Iframe Ghost Bug

Tags: ipad, iframe, safari, css-position

If iframe is in the page with div which has position fixed and in iframe there is some element with position fixed, iframe will disappear after typing in some input/textarea field in iframe.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 250px; height: 250px; top: 0px; right: 0px; border: solid 2px red;">           
      <iframe src="iframe.html" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></iframe>           
    </div>         
  </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: fixed">         
      <input type="text" placeholder="type here" /><br>
      start typing above in iPad and after 1st char this iframe will be moved to the left side and after 2nd char it will completely dissapear
      (tested on iPad 2; iOS 9.0.2; Safari 601.1)
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

demo: http://goo.gl/W0VDbh

Do you have idea how to fix it? Note: positions fixed can not be removed/replaced, in index.html can not add global styles - just for div and its children elements.